# overleaf: Trouble with epstopdf: File 'foo-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found

Tags: pdftex, ieeetran, overleaf, epstopdf

I wrote a draft on overleaf and wanted to upload some .eps figures into my doc (pdfTex used). I tried to compile those .eps files in my local machine (VS Code) and it worked. However, on overleaf I cannot get one .eps file compiled. This .eps file is of 30573KB. But I don't think the size of the file matters because I also compiled two 30,000 KB files on overleaf which actually worked.
The log said:

```
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <fig9_Backscatter.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-03-18 08:47:09
(epstopdf)                    size: 31293299 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <fig9_Backscatter-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-03-18 08:48:09
(epstopdf)                    size: 9347072 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=fig9_Backscatter-eps-conver
ted-to.pdf fig9_Backscatter.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 815.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file /compile/fig9_Backscatter-eps-converted-to.pdf): 
xpdf: reading PDF image failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
[![the fatal error][1]][1]
```

I used code like this:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig10_slope.eps}
\caption{Map of ...
}
\label{fig:fig10}
\end{figure*}
```

I searched in the texstack and found that all similar answer are referred to the local IDE. So is there anyone who can help me with this issue but on overleaf? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide a full (but minimal) example not a sniplet. The preamble and documentclass you use are also important. That is one massive EPS. Why is is taht large?

Comment: Hi @daleif I added my documentclass and all the pkgs I used.

Comment: Please reduce it to only those needed for the example (anything not graphics related could possibly be removed). Also would it be possible to have access to the EPS? Additionally when down to a minimal example, please post the full log of a compilation of that, not just a part of it. There may be other things relevant in that log.

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ With such huge .eps files, it's likely that the eps-to-pdf conversion during pdflatex has taken too long, exceeding your Overleaf plan's timeout limit. So it's likely that the .eps file wasn't successfully converted to a .pdf at all, hence that message. We would recommend that you optimise your .eps file so that the file size is smaller, or pre-convert it to a .pdf locally—it's usually much smaller. Such large .eps images might be caused by inappropriate export settings, so you may want to check your  original drawing application.

Comment: Thanks @lianTzeL

Comment: I will check the .eps file original drawing application. I drew it by python, it's a 4x6 subplots. So how can I pre-convert it to pdf? because I need .eps format to reserve its tiny feature.

Comment: Why do you need it in EPS? That sentence does not make sence. Normally LaTeX comes with a command line tool to convert EPS to PDF called, `epstopdf`, great tool. Though, I don't know if overleaf provides direct access to it.

Comment: You can try to convert it to .pdf with the excellent Siep Kroonenberg's `epspdf[tk]`.

Comment: you must _already_ have converted the files to pdf on your local machine as you said it worked there, you will have pdf versions of the eps files generated by your local epstopdf

Comment: @daleif because eps is vector based and will not lose features

Comment: @Bernard Thanks but how can I use epspdf[tk]?

Comment: (1) Now I want to see that EPS, never seen a vector based EPS at 30Mb before. Do you have millions of points in there? A correctly done EPS in vectorgraphics should not need to be 30Mb (I'm suspecting bitmap inside that EPS, just because it is EPS does not mean that it is vector graphics, it can contain bitmaps)  (2) EPS correctly copnverted to PDF is also vector graphics (if the original is vector graphics).

Comment: I suggest to make the conversion on your own system. Personally, I use it under Windows. It has an easy-to-use graphic UI, and you need to have ghostscript installed on your system.

Comment: wow I also use windows, so just install ghostscript?